# Add dash in the URL

Tags: python, flask, routes

I want to add dash in my URL when flask automatically generate the URL.

Code shown in the below:

```
@main.route('/post_detail/<string:title>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_detail(title):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first_or_404()
    return render_template('post_detail.html', post=post)
```

Since i use FLASK built-in convert in route, when there is space in title(e.g,title is`title title`), the url will be like this `xxx.title title`,what should i do to add dash in the url, like `xxx.title_title`.

And I don't want add dash in my title(e.g, title is `title_title`)

here is my template:

**post_detail.html**

```
<h1 color='black'>{{ post.title | replace('_', ' ') }}</h1>
<h2 class="subheading">{{ post.summary }}</h2>
<span class="meta">Posted by <a href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a></span>
```

`and **post_list.html**

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="post-preview">
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.post_detail', title=post.title) }}">
        <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
        <h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.summary }}</h3>
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">{{ post.author.username }}</a></p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want to create a `Post` record with title **'this is a title'** or **'this_is_a_title'**? How do you send the post request? submitting a form? using a http client like requests, postman? In general, spaces are replaced with %20 in html charset when the url includes a space; i.e., Chrome replaces the spaces automatically. Normally, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: I send the post request by submitting a form, i dont want change my title so i come up with this issue. As you said, but firefox did not change the 'space' into '%20'

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see your template.

Anyway, here is a working solution for your problem.

The important thing is how you construct the details url in the template.

See the usage of `url_for` with a parameter. Also, check the browsers address line when you display the details page of the post including spaces in its title.

All replacement for html charset will be performed by the *template engine*, so you don't need to worry about it.

In your implementation, you can remove the `get_post` method and `POSTS` list as you are probably using *SQLAlchemy ORM*. They are just for quick testing.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, abort, render_template

main = Flask(__name__)

POSTS = [
    {'title': 'this_is_a_title'},
    {'title': 'this_is_another_title'},
    {'title': 'this title contains space'},
]

def get_post(title):
    for post in POSTS:
        if post['title'] == title:
            return post
    return None

@main.route('/post_list', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_list():
    return render_template('post_list.html', posts=POSTS)

@main.route('/post_detail/<string:title>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_detail(title):
    #post = Post.query.filter_by(title=title).first_or_404()
    post = get_post(title)
    if post is None:
        abort(404)
    return render_template('post_detail.html', post=post)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main.run(debug=True)
```

**templates/post_list.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>POST LIST</h1>
    {% for post in posts %}
      <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
      <a href="{{ url_for('post_detail', title=post.title) }}">details</a>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

**templates/post_detail.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>POST DETAIL</h1>
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I think you don't get the point or I confused you. What I want is to change the `space` into `_` in url without dash in parameter `title`, i dont want to add dash in my title.

Comment: Yes, I am really confused. Who is adding dashes into your url? Why do you need to replace spaces with underscore? And, how will you filter your records by title with underscores while their original form contains spaces in the database? If you can show your related templates, I try to understand and help you.

Comment: Cause i feel awkward to fill the address with space, so i try to replace spaces with underscore. From your suggestion, I come up with idea that replace underscore with space in template, the (Jinja) template is `<h1 color='black'>{{ post.title | replace('_', ' ') }}</h1>`. but I have to add underscore in my title. This is only a compromise method. But, anyway, thanks a lot : )